# Add a left join in Laravel query/subquery builder

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to add a left join to this query I've been using to get nPerGroup of related records.  I've created the query in SQL just don't know how to convert it to Laravel query builder code.

The reason I want to add a `left join` is for performance purposes. When I fetch all columns from the get-go, the query takes too load to complete (around 6 secs on 400k rows), whereas with a `left join` that's cut into only half a second.

I've tried adding a `left join` after the `mergeBindings`, however, I could not figure out how to specify the columns I need in the first select.  No matter what I tried the first select always stayed as `select *`.

Here's the Laravel scope code that I need to change:

```
public function scopeNPerGroup($query, $group, $n = 10, $columns)
{

    // queried table
    $table = ($this->getTable());

    // initialize MySQL variables inline
    $query->from(DB::raw("(SELECT @rank:=0, @group:=0) as vars, {$table}"));

    // if no columns already selected, let's select *
    if (! $query->getQuery()->columns && empty($columns)) {
        $query->select("{$table}.*");
    }
    elseif (!empty($columns)) {
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            $query->addSelect($column);
        }
    }

    // make sure column aliases are unique
    $groupAlias = 'group_'.md5(time());
    $rankAlias  = 'rank_'.md5(time());

    // apply mysql variables
    $query->addSelect(DB::raw(
        "@rank := IF(@group = {$group}, @rank+1, 1) as {$rankAlias}, @group := {$group} as {$groupAlias}"
    ));

    // make sure first order clause is the group order
    $query->getQuery()->orders = (array) $query->getQuery()->orders;
    array_unshift($query->getQuery()->orders, ['column' => $group, 'direction' => 'asc']);

    // prepare subquery
    $subQuery = $query->toSql();

    // prepare new main base Query\Builder
    $newBase = $this->newQuery()
        ->from(DB::raw("({$subQuery}) as {$table}"))
        ->mergeBindings($query->getQuery())
        ->where($rankAlias, '<=', $n)
        ->getQuery();

    // replace underlying builder to get rid of previous clauses
    $query->setQuery($newBase);
}
```

Here's the SQL that's produced by the code above:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT `positions`.`id`, 
               `positions`.`keyword_id`, 
               `positions`.`position`, 
               @rank := IF(@group = keyword_id, @rank + 1, 1) AS 
               rank_fa9d7a6f55c38becc0b28f348651a856, 
               @group := keyword_id                           AS 
                      group_fa9d7a6f55c38becc0b28f348651a856 
        FROM   (SELECT @rank := 0, 
                       @group := 0) AS vars, 
               positions 
        ORDER  BY `keyword_id` ASC, 
                  `created_at` DESC) AS positions 
WHERE  `rank_fa9d7a6f55c38becc0b28f348651a856` <= '2' 
       AND `positions`.`keyword_id` IN ('1', '2', ...)
```

And here's the SQL I need it to produce instead: (Could be different as long as it accomplishes the same thing, which is fetching the additional `positions.url` column.)

```
SELECT `positionsA`.`id`, `positionsA`.`keyword_id`, `positionsA`.`position`, `positions`.`url`
FROM   (SELECT `positions`.`id`, 
               `positions`.`keyword_id`, 
               `positions`.`position`, 
               @rank := IF(@group = keyword_id, @rank + 1, 1) AS 
               rank_e2d9373d3bb35d6aabe9ffc57ff29c1c, 
               @group := keyword_id                           AS 
                      group_e2d9373d3bb35d6aabe9ffc57ff29c1c 
        FROM   (SELECT @rank := 0, 
                       @group := 0) AS vars, 
               positions 
        ORDER  BY `keyword_id` ASC, 
                  `created_at` DESC) AS positionsA 
LEFT JOIN `positions` on `positionsA`.`id` = `positions`.`id`
WHERE  `rank_e2d9373d3bb35d6aabe9ffc57ff29c1c` <= '2' 
       AND `positionsA`.`keyword_id` IN ('1', '2', ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you neeed something like this:

```
$newBase = $this->newQuery()
    ->from(DB::raw("({$subQuery}) as {$table}A"))
    ->leftJoin('positions', 'positionsA.id', '=', 'positions.id')
    ->mergeBindings($query->getQuery())
    ->where($rankAlias, '<=', $n)
    ->getQuery();
```

Comment: Yep I had gotten that far too, but I couldn't figure out how to select the specific fields in the first `SELECT` statement. It always keeps going for `SELECT *` That works too but it takes like 2.5s to run whereas my raw query runs in around half a second with pre-selected columns.  That's kinda why I'd like to get it as close to the raw query as possible.

Comment: Actually that's not the reason it's running slower.  The reason is actually I need to figure out how to change the `positions.keyword_id` to `positionsA.keyword_id`.  That's the culprit.  However, I think that part is generated by the parent model where it's fetching the relationship.  Any idea how to change that?